# bash script - Iterate list of files without extention in a directory

Tags: bash

I want to iterate all the files in a directory in a bash script.

1. List all files with extentions .LOG .txt .MAP .TL9*
2. List all files which have no extention.

I am trying this :

> `for file in *.{LOG,txt,MAP,TL9*}; do`

I want to list the files, that only ends with above extension.
So, I do not want to list a file: temp.txt.EXT because it does not end with above given extentions. Similarly I don't want this to be reported temp.TL94.JPG or temp.TL9.JPG.

But in this above for loop, how do i insert the check which gives me the file with no extention?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `extglob`, you can do this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob

for file in @(!(*.*)|*.@(csv|LOG|TL9!(*.*))); do
   echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: Yes... but I am using this *.@(LOG|txt|MAP|TL9) !(*.*)

Comment: It is exact same glob expression as mine (which I posted earlier) but broken down into 2 separate globs.

Comment: Its showing me files like Name.LOG.TMP (because I think it has .LOG in the middle). But i don't this file. I want all the files "ending" with LOG|txt|MAP|TL9* only @anubhava

Comment: That's not correct. It won't list `Name.LOG.TMP`. It will only list files ending with `.LOG`

Comment: My bad. I gave wrong file name. It was showing me this file Name.TL98.JPG even though i don't want it as it DOES NOT end with .TL9* @anubhava

Answer (score 1):

With `extglob`:

```
*.@(LOG|txt|MAP|TL9) !(*.*)
```

- `*.@(LOG|txt|MAP|TL9)` matches all `.LOG`, `txt`, `.MAP`, and `.TL9` files
- `!(*.*)` matches all files except ones having `.` in name

Enable `extglob` first if not enabled:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: "@" didn't worked inside a script. I had to use "+".

Comment: Its showing me files like Name.LOG.TMP (because I think it has .LOG in the middle). But i don't this file. I want all the files "ending" with LOG|txt|MAP|TL9* only

Comment: @PuneetJain Working fine for me. Are you on `bash`?

Comment: My bad. I gave wrong file name. It was showing me this file Name.TL98.JPG even though i don't want it as it DOES NOT end with .TL9* @heemayl

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `find` command to list files with extension `MAP`, `LOG`, `TL9`or without any extension at all.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=`find . -type f -regex ".*[\.LOG|\.MAP|\.TL9]" -o ! -name "*.*"`

for file in $files
do
  echo $file
done
```